# INSERT INTO not working in IF block - T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

im working on procedure which should transfer number of items (value @p_count) from old store to new store

```
SET @countOnOldStore = (SELECT "count" FROM ProductStore WHERE StoreId = @p_oldStoreId AND ProductId = @p_productID)
    SET @countOnNewStore = (SELECT "count" FROM ProductStore WHERE StoreId = @p_newStoreID AND ProductId = @p_productID)
    SET @ShiftedCount = @countOnOldStore - @p_count
    SET @newStoreAfterShift = @countOnNewStore + @p_count
    IF @ShiftedCount > 0
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM ProductStore WHERE storeId = @p_oldStoreId and productID = @p_productID
            INSERT INTO ProductStore (storeId,productId,"count") VALUES (@p_oldStoreId,@p_productID,@ShiftedCount)

            DELETE FROM ProductStore WHERE storeId = @p_newStoreID and productID = @p_productID
            INSERT INTO ProductStore (storeId,productId,"count") VALUES (@p_newStoreID,@p_productID,@newStoreAfterShift)
        END 
    ELSE
        PRINT 'ERROR'
```

well ... second insert is not working. I cant figure it out. It says

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'count', table 'dbo.ProductStore'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Can anyone see problem and explain it to me ? Its school project

Comment: try printing @newStoreAfterShift value. It seems to get null and ProductStore  doesnt accept null or the column  count

Comment: Try to print `@ShiftedCount`, `@newStoreAfterShift`. The error log is very clear that you're inserting null, but it's not allowed.

Comment: Why do you `DELETE` and `INSERT` rather than just doing an `UPDATE`?

Comment: i wanted to handle situation where there is no productId in storeId i need update.  Peter Horvath i think i can handle one -1. Thanks for nothing ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your entire query should just be:

```
UPDATE ProductStore
SET [count] = [count] + CASE
      WHEN storeId = @p_NewStoreID THEN @p_Count
      ELSE -@p_Count END
WHERE
    productID = @p_ProductID and
    storeID in (@p_NewStoreID,@p_OldStoreID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If either value in the following is `NULL`, the total will be `NULL`:

```
SET @newStoreAfterShift = @countOnNewStore + @p_count
```

Check both values (`@countOnNewStore, @p_count`) for `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not assigning any value to @p_count, so it is `NULL` and so are @ShiftedCount and @newStoreAfterShift.